# Using len for text but discarding spaces in the count

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I am trying to create a program which counts the number of characters in a string which the user inputs, but I want to discard any spaces that the user enters.

```
def main():
    full_name = str(input("Please enter in a full name: ")).split(" ")

    for x in full_name:
        print(len(x))


main()
```

Using this, I can get the number of the characters in each word, without spaces, but I don't know how to add each number together and print the total.

Comment: Why are you `split`ting the phrase?

Comment: I thought I would split them and then count them up that way. This allows me to count it without the spaces, but I realize now that it's not very efficient to do that, lol.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Count the length and subtract the number of spaces:

```
>>> full_name = input("Please enter in a full name: ")
Please enter in a full name: john smith
>>> len(full_name) - full_name.count(' ')
9
>>> len(full_name)
```

Comment: Brilliant! As you can see, I'm a beginner programmer. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: @Izento: no sweat! Since you are new to SO, please [consider accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 6):

Use `sum` with a generator expression:

```
>>> text = 'foo  bar  spam'
>>> sum(len(x) for x in text.split())
10
```

Or `str.translate` with `len`:

```
>>> from string import whitespace
>>> len(text.translate(None, whitespace)) #Handles all types of whitespace characters
10
```

Comment: This requires the creation of new lists with each `split`ed chunk, which has O(n) space complexity. Would be better to subtract the number of spaces from the total length (no extra space + O(n) time). I like the `translate` idea, though

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you just do:

```
>>> mystr = input("Please enter in a full name: ")
Please enter in a full name: iCodez wrote this
>>> len(mystr.replace(" ", ""))
15
>>> len(mystr)
17
>>>
```

This gets the length of the string minus the spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I can propose a few versions.

You can replace each space with an empty string and calculate the length:

```
len(mystr.replace(" ", ""))
```

You can calculate the length of the whole string and subtract the number of spaces:

```
len(mystr) - mystr.count(' ')
```

Or you can sum the lengths of all substrings after splitting the string with spaces:

```
sum(map(len, mystr.split(' ')))
```

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of characters excluding spaces, you can simply do:

```
>>> full_name = "John DOE"
>>> len(full_name) - full_name.count(' ')
7
```

Answer (score 0):

Some code as close as possible to your original:

```
def main():
    full_name = input("Please enter in a full name: ").split()
    total = 0
    for x in full_name:
        total += len(x)
    print(total)
```

However, I think `len(full_name) - full_name.count(' ')` is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
sum(1 for c in s if c!=' ')
```

Which avoids any unnecessary temporary string or list.

Answer (score 0):

Explained in comments

```
string1 = input ()

# just when the condition is true add 1 
res = sum(1 for c in string1 if c!=' ')

# it's shorter and still works
res2 = sum(c!=' ' for c in string1)

# summing ones may be more explicit but it's unnecessary
print(res, res2)
```

```
c v s
3 3

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score -1):

I also found that this works. I am a beginner programmer and I did not understand anything that was going on in the other explanations. I think that this might be a little easier to understand for a beginner beginner.

```
full_name = str(input("Please enter in your full name: "))
spaces = str(" ")
spaces_name = str(len(full_name) - len(spaces))

print("Your name " + full_name + " has " + spaces_name + "charictures")
```

Comment: Hi Caleb and thanks for joining and answering, except I'm afraid the answer is incorrect so I'm going to have to mark it down.  Your 'spaces' is always going to be a single space and hence, the `len(" ")` is always going to be 1 so you're simply subtracting one from the length of the entered name.  If the name entered is "Madonna" or "Lee Harvey Oswald" for example, it'll be wrong.

As an aside, you don't need `str(" ")` The `" "` is already a string so it's just `spaces = " "`.