# Calculating number of characters per document

Tags: python, dataframe, text, character

I am working on a document (a pandas dataframe) containing thousands of rows of text message (dtype=str) and their classification (spam or not spam):

```css
  -
                                         text    spam
0 Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only    0
1 Ok lar... Joking wif u oni...                    0
2 Free entry in 2 a wkly comp to win FA Cup fina   1
3 U dun say so early hor... U c already then say   0
4 Nah I don't think he goes to usf, he lives aro   0
5 FreeMsg Hey there darling it's been 3 week's n   1
6 WINNER!! As a valued network customer you have   1
```

I want to calculate the number of characters for each message (i.e., each row), make them into a separate column ('length'), sum their total and divide by len(document) to get the average length (number of characters) of the document.
What will be the most efficient way to get this stat in the presence of non-character spaces? Do I just apply len() on each row entry in the entire dataframe?

Thank you.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: `df['text'].str.len()`

Comment: 'g', 'o', include non-character spaces (e.g., empty spaces). I seem to have forgotten to add a 'not" in the last line of my question threat, I will edit it. Also, I have tried 'df['text'].str.len()' before but kept getting inconsistent result, must be some errors on my part.

Comment: Hold on, since I initiated this thread, I will like to know how to exclude non-character space from character count. So that this thread wouldn't be a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
for row in ('Insert/file/path/here'):
        print (len(row))
```

Comment: Thanks! This appears to be a more elegant solution. Can it be modified to tease out non-character spaces?

Comment: You could use row.count(' ') to count the number of spaces and subtract it from the length of row.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669001/using-len-in-texts-but-discluding-spaces-in-the-count

Comment: Thanks again. So which part deals with non-character spaces? row.count(' ')?

Comment: If by non character spaces you mean the actual physical spaces, the space between parenthesis means that the row.count feature is counting the number of spaces. And thank you for giving me top answer!

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying this to me.

Comment: Anytime! I'm glad I could be of service.

Comment: Let me know if you have any more questions

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks again for helping on this.