# How to find total number of characters in paragraph(excluding spaces) in PYTHON?

Tags: python, python-3.x

finding total words in paragraph by using split command was easy but what to do when to find number of characters in paragraph using PYTHON?

Comment: split by space, then sum all the sums of characters of the resulting string list.

Comment: just replace spaces with an empty string and get the length

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using len in texts but discluding spaces in the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669001/using-len-in-texts-but-discluding-spaces-in-the-count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your string (that removes spaces and gives a list of string), and then count characters of each word and sum the total.

```
myString = "Hello you !" # 11 characters

totalNCharacters = sum([len(x) for x in mystring.split()]) 

print(totalCharacters) # output: 9
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go for a listcomprehension:

```
len([c for c in "la a a" if c not in (' ', '\n') ])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do that, so I wondered how they fair against each other so I timed them. I implemented all the methods in this question and any additional ones from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669001/using-len-in-texts-but-discluding-spaces-in-the-count).

```
from timeit import timeit

setup = """
from collections import Counter
import string

text = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In malesuada eget tortor vel tempor. Cras condimentum risus a mi sagittis, at lobortis dui efficitur. Suspendisse fringilla ligula at eros consequat aliquet. Praesent volutpat sapien non aliquam cursus. Suspendisse auctor sapien ac leo luctus scelerisque. Cras eget fringilla mauris. Vivamus fermentum, nisl et mollis consequat, nisl sapien lacinia ex, ac finibus eros dui vel sapien. Curabitur dignissim porttitor ex sed vestibulum. Nullam nulla lorem, aliquam in turpis at, egestas tempor turpis. Aenean at lorem molestie, placerat eros in, tempus dui. Morbi magna nulla, blandit ac vestibulum faucibus, luctus sit amet libero. Ut quis lorem porta, cursus nunc id, malesuada mauris. Aenean luctus diam ac tortor rutrum mattis. Donec ultrices nibh quis est varius pellentesque. Donec tempor, est vel commodo ultricies, mauris tortor egestas orci, ut hendrerit orci ex eget risus. In eu ullamcorper odio, lacinia auctor urna.'

def split_join(s):
    return len(''.join(s.split()))

def list_comprehension(s):
    return len([c for c in s if c != " "])

def sum_len_split(s):
    return sum([len(x) for x in s.split()])

def map_len_split(s):
    return sum(map(len, s.split()))

def conventional_loop(s):
    x = 0
    for n in s:
        if not n.isspace():
            x += 1
    return x

def replace_space(s):
    return len(s.replace(" ", ""))

def counter(s):
    valid_letters = string.ascii_letters
    count = Counter(s)
    return sum(count[letter] for letter in valid_letters)

def discount_space(s):
    return len(s) - s.count(" ")
"""    

functions = [line[4:-4] for line in setup.split('\n')
             if line.startswith('def ')]

n = 100000
results = []
for function in functions:
    results.append((timeit('{}(text)'.format(function), setup=setup, number=n), function))
results.sort()

for time, function in results:
    print(function, time)
```

Results

```
discount_space 0.1687837346025738
replace_space 0.5508266038467227
split_join 1.231192897388388
map_len_split 1.5719588628305754
sum_len_split 2.2983778970212896
list_comprehension 5.715995796916212
counter 7.133700537385263
conventional_loop 11.01061941802605
```

Of course, unless you have millions of characters in your string, performance isn't an issue and code clarity is more important. In that case I would still argue that `discount_space()` is the most clear and direct.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def count_letters(word, valid_letters=string.ascii_letters):
    count = Counter(word) # this counts all the letters
    return sum(count[letter] for letter in valid_letters) # valid letters
```

Answer (score 0):

by characters, I assume mean anything not whitespace, meaning punctuation included. This is one way it can be done:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

s = 'abc  def   ghi....\n":)*9.w wer'
x = 0
for n in s:
    if not n.isspace():
        x += 1

print("total number of characters is {}".format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
paragraph = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Remove the spaces and print the length:

```
print(len(paragraph.replace(" ", "")))
# 35
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use **split** and **join**:

```
def char_count(s):
    return len(''.join(s.split()))
```