# How to find the length of a string without counting spaces?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I want to know how to count the length of a string without counting spaces?

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(len(a))
```

Comment: you mean you wanna count only letters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using len for text but discarding spaces in the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19669001/using-len-for-text-but-discarding-spaces-in-the-count)

Comment: `strr = "Hello World!" count = 0 for i in strr: if i.isalpha() == True: count += 1 print(count)`

Comment: Literally just the space character or anything that spaces (or has no space)? Thinking tab, newline, etc... And what about emoji?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
a = "Hello, World!"
print(len(a) - a.count(' '))
```

Comment: This is exactly the accepted answer in the duplicate. No need to repeat...

Comment: The comment about duplicate post was made after my answer.

Comment: Ok still... No reason to have duplicated answers on the site